# Trying to install Wine on Zorin OS 16

Tags: wine, zorin

i want to get wine on my linux computer (Zorin OS 16), but when i type in the terminal "`sudo apt install wine`" i get this message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine64 (>= 6.0.3~repack-1+zorin1) or
                 wine32 (>= 6.0.3~repack-1+zorin1)
        Depends: wine64 (< 6.0.3~repack-1+zorin1.1~) or
                 wine32 (< 6.0.3~repack-1+zorin1.1~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install wine`

Comment: https://wine.htmlvalidator.com/install-wine-on-zorin-16.html

Comment: i tried those, but it didnt work. i have a laptop that also has Zorin 16 on it and i never got an error while installing wine on that, just on my pc

Comment: sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Comment: Compare /etc/apt/sources.list on pc and notebook